# About JDBC beginner tutorial

Tags: jdbc

I am new to jdbc.I dont know anything about jdbc.I want complete and detailed beginner tutorial on jdbc.
Can any one suggest me the links or notes for the tutorial

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could have just Googled it. Here is a good one:

http://www.jdbc-tutorial.com/

And for a detailed tutorial see this one: http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Database/JDBC20Intro/JDBC20.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [JDBC Tutorial from a Stanford Professor](http://infolab.stanford.edu/~ullman/fcdb/oracle/or-jdbc.html).

Here is a [Beginner's JDBC Tutorial](http://www.raima.com/jdbc-tutorial/) that can be used for any database management system; including MySQL, Oracle, PostgreSQL, RDM, etc.

Here is a JDBC Introduction from Oracle: docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/overview/index.html

Answer (score 0):

JDBC stands for Java Database Connectivity is an Application Programming Interface(API) which has many interfaces which allows a java program to connect to database like MS Access, Oracle, MYSQL etc.

There are 4 types of Drivers :
1: JDBC-ODBC Bridge Driver
2: JDBC-Native API
3: JDBC-Net pure Java
4: 100% Pure Java

For more Details Refer following link:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/jdbc-driver-types.htm

For program with MS Access Refer following links:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35018/Access-MS-Access-Databases-from-Java

http://java2all.com/technology/jdbc/jdbc-example/jdbc-example-with-access

Answer (score 0):

Refer to [JDBC Developer's guide](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/JJDBC/toc.htm) on Oracle site.